# Schwinn sidewinder 21 gear slipping?

Tags: chain, crankset, freewheel, freehub

If rear tire is off the ground, the wheel will spin when pedaled.

When wheel is on the ground the pedals will move the chain in any gear but will not move the rear wheel.  The chain is not losing contact with any sprocket cogs.

Why doesn't the rear wheel turn?

Comment: It sounds like the cogs in the freewheel/freehub mechanism are slipping.  But it could be a few other things.

Comment: Clarifying, when there's a bit of resistance, the chain turns the cogs(the cassette)  but the wheel doesn't turn?

Comment: In other words: sitting on the bike and pedalling moves the chain but doesn't make the bike move?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I pedal the rear wheel is not turning](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/when-i-pedal-the-rear-wheel-is-not-turning)